# Using uDig/Geotools to visualize data created with Neo4j Spatial?

Tags: neo4j, geotools, neo4j-spatial

I have created a test database with Neo4j Spatial Java API. Is there any tutorial how to use uDig/Geotools for visualizing the spatial data?

There is a section at the Neo4j Spatial Instructions page (http://neo4j.github.io/spatial/) called "Using Neo4j Spatial with uDig" that says "For more info head over to Neo4j Wiki on uDig" but the link is not working.

I found a uDig Quickstart tutorial (http://udig.github.io/docs/dev/SDKQuickstart/SDKQuickstart.html) to setup uDig but I do not know how to use it with Neo4j Spatial. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I see this was answered in the neo4j google group, but for completeness let's answer here. Michael Hunger found a Japanese site with a mirror of the old wiki pages at http://oss.infoscience.co.jp/neo4j/wiki.neo4j.org/content/Neo4j_Spatial_in_uDig.html.

And Peter added a proxy page into the github wiki pointing to these mirrors at https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/wiki

Peter also asked that anyone working with Neo4j Spatial and uDig consider volunteering to port the old wiki into the github wiki, including any changes required to work with newer Neo4j Spatial and newer uDig.